# HQL query to filter date from datetime data

Tags: hql, datetime-format

I want to convert datetime format to string format in HQL count. 
For example, I have redundant attendance data in each day of month of multiple employee which I need to count and get distinct data for a single day.

```
select Count(distinct att.AttDate) from AttendanceTable att where att.AttDate between '" + startDate.Date + "' and '" + endDate.Date + "'
```

but this query counting each and every datetime data because of time value. So I need to convert datetime into string.

Answer (score 1):

HQL allows only [certain set of functions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions).

Try

```
select count(distinct (
    day(att.AttDate) + 
    31 * month(att.AttDate) + 
    366 * year(att.AttDate) ))
```

You could try `str()` or `cast()` but the result won't be consistent over different databases.